# "std::bad_alloc" exception when traversing directory using boost

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, filesystems

Ubuntu 18.04
boost 1.65.1

I'm trying to traverse my directory and get all of the file paths, here's the code I copied from stackoverflow:

```
fs::directory_iterator endIter;
for (fs::directory_iterator iter(srcImageDir); iter != fs::directory_iterator(); iter++)
{
    cout << iter->path().string() << endl;
}
```

But after I compiled and executed it, I got error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Please show me what's wrong, thanks in advancce.

Comment: Tried, but same error.

Comment: I think it's not about the "cout ..." because if I remove the line, there's still the same error.

Comment: Just might be the way you have built boost. Did you build it youself?

Comment: No, I used other people's.

Comment: Hum. Rule out some other things before embarking on building Boost yourself (it's quite a learning curve).

Comment: Do you perhaps have a symlink to a parent directory inside the tree being examined?  (I feel like you would have mentioned a very long execution before `std::bad_alloc`, though.)

Comment: Finally fixed by rebuild on target machine~